# PGI compiler creates an error with a fortran type-bound procedures

Tags: fortran, pgi

I am working on a Fortran code. And I have to deal with many different type of output file. So to manage all of them, I use type objects.

Until now, I have compiled my code with `gfortran` on linux and windows (and `ifort` on linux) ; and it works as expected.

Because, I want in a close future to integrate GPU parallel computing to my code with OpenACC, I have to be able to compile it with `pgfortran` (the PGI compiler for Fortran).
Here arrives my problem, the compilation (with `pgfortran 18-4-0` on windows) returns me no warning, but at the execute the code crashes with a strange error: `[Exit 3221225477] test.exe`.

Therefore, I tried to isolate the problem, in order to solve it. I finally get the following MWE:

```
MODULE VTK_IO
   implicit none

   type, abstract :: FormatVTK
   contains
      procedure(VTK_open_file),nopass, deferred :: open_file_VTK
      procedure(VTK_close_file),nopass, deferred :: close_file_VTK
   end type FormatVTK

   type, extends(FormatVTK) :: FormatAscii
   contains
      procedure, nopass :: open_file_VTK => open_file_ascii
      procedure, nopass :: close_file_VTK => close_file_ascii
   end type FormatAscii

   type,  public      :: VTKfileHandler
      integer                    :: unit
      class(FormatVTK), allocatable    :: type
   end type VTKfileHandler

   abstract interface
      subroutine VTK_open_file( fd )
         import VTKfileHandler
         class(VTKfileHandler), intent(inout) :: fd
      end subroutine
      subroutine VTK_close_file(fd)
         import VTKfileHandler
         class(VTKfileHandler), intent(in)    :: fd
      end subroutine
   end interface


contains
   subroutine open_file_ascii( fd )
      implicit none
      class(VTKfileHandler), intent(inout) :: fd
      character(len=80)                     :: f
      !-------------------------------------------------------------------------

      write(unit=*, fmt=*) 'open_file_ascii: start'
      ! stop 6969
      f='test_file.txt'

      open(newunit    = fd%unit,          &
         file       = trim(adjustl(f)), &
         form       = 'FORMATTED',      & ! FORMATTED
         access     = 'STREAM',         & ! SEQUENTIAL
         action     = 'WRITE',          &
         status     = 'REPLACE')

      write(unit=fd%unit,fmt='(100A)') "# vtk DataFile Version "
      write(unit=*, fmt=*) 'open_file_ascii: end'
   end subroutine open_file_ascii

   subroutine close_file_ascii(fd)
      implicit none
      class(VTKfileHandler), intent(in) :: fd
      !-------------------------------------------------------------------------

      close(unit=fd%unit)
      write(unit=*, fmt=*) 'close_file_ascii: done'
   end subroutine close_file_ascii
end module vtk_IO


PROGRAM Test_open
   USE VTK_IO
   IMPLICIT NONE

   type :: OutputFile
      class (VTKfileHandler), allocatable :: VTKfile
   end type OutputFile

   type (OutputFile) :: OutsFiles
   !----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   print*,  'START: Test_open'

   Print*,'initialise_outputs: start'
      allocate(VTKfileHandler :: OutsFiles%VTKfile )
      allocate(FormatAscii :: OutsFiles%VTKfile%type)
   Print*,'initialise_outputs: end'
     call OutsFiles%VTKfile%type%open_file_VTK(OutsFiles%VTKfile)
     call  OutsFiles%VTKfile%type%close_file_VTK(OutsFiles%VTKfile)
   print*,  'END: Test_open'
END PROGRAM Test_open
```

It seems like the type-bound procedure `open_file_VTK` is not targetting the procedure `open_file_ascii`. I think that the compiler get lost with the type-bounded procedure. For example, if I remove the `OutsFiles` and use directly a VTKfile in the main, it works. But, of course, I need this embedding type `OutputFile`, in my big code ; otherwise it would be too easy.

So is it a bug from the compiler ? Or can I do something to solve this problem ?

Comment: I can't see any procedure pointers in your code. Just some  type-bound procedures. What is the output of your  test code? Why do you believe, why does it seem?

Comment: @VladimirF You are right, it's just type-bound procedures, I corrected my mistakes in the question. 
I get a `.txt` file plus messages from the `print` until the end with `gfortran`.
While I get no output, only the error code with `pgfortran`, But if I put a `stop` in the code before `call OutsFiles%VTKfile%type%open_file_VTK(OutsFiles%VTKfile)`, I get the messages `print`. If I put the stop after, or even inside the procedure, I get only the error code again.

Comment: Looks like a PGI bug to me.  On Linux the code compiles but seg faults when calling a function pointer.  I assume it's the same issue on Windows.  Hence, I've created a problem report (TPR#26432) and sent it to our engineers for further investigation.  If you'd like us to notify you when this issue has been addressed, please send a note to PGI Customer Service (trs@pgroup.com) and will add you're email address to the report.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that gfortran supports [OpenACC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OpenACC)?

Comment: @Steve Yes, I am aware of that point. But from what I understood, it is less efficient than PGI compilers on that point. And I am thinking to use the gfortran option to continue my tests if the problem comes from the PGI compilers and do not update quickly enough.

Comment: The statement in the original post concerning of the need to compile with pgfortran because of OpenACC could suggest to an uninformed reader that gfortran does not support OpenACC.  I've corrected that erroneous suggestion.